# gcc and clang: thread library is successfully included but nothing won't be compiled with that

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, pthreads

I've got specific error that I haven't encountered before.

*Before I'll start, I need to say that I work on a server and have no root rights.* `/usr/bin` *and* `/usr/local/bin` *are missing many packages and because of that I had been obliged to install necessary packages (including `gcc-5.4.0`) locally in my `$HOME` directory and everything worked fine until today*

Something happened and since I cannot compile any program that uses `<thread>`, `<mutex>` and anything that related to multithreading. It throws many errors in log like (this is llvm building error):

```
mutex.h:69:14: error: ‘condition_variable’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
 typedef std::condition_variable Condition;
```

I've been looking for solution and many say that you need to pass `-std=c++11` flag. I think that this is not the reason, but I found something interesting:

I created a simple program just to check whether it can be compiled:

```
#include <mutex>

std::mutex m;

int main() {}
```

1. Used locally installed `g++`: `$HOME/g++ -std=c++11 -lpthread mut.cc`: **FAILED**
2. Used globally installed `g++`: `/usr/bin/g++ -std=c++11 -lpthread mut.cc`: **SUCCESS**

I suppose this error somehow related to linking with `libpthread`.
The same happens with locally installed `clang++`

**UPDATE**: An idea came up to me that if the header exists but it doesn't take names from it, then it means that there should be some disabled defined within it. So, I found source of header `<thread>` (`$HOME/local/include/c++/5.4.0/thread`) and enabled these ones:

```
#define _GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS 1
#define _GLIBCXX_USE_C99_STDINT_TR1 1
```

the same I made for `<mutex>` and compilation started up. I don't understand how could they be disabled in linux system?

Comment: What's the error you got in that last test using `$HOME/g++`?

Comment: `mut.cc:3:6: error: ‘mutex’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
 std::mutex m;`

Comment: OK, so it's not a linking problem but a compiler problem. Are you including the `<mutex>` header in `mut.cc`?

Comment: Yes, of course. Look at the snippet

Comment: What versions are both your home g++ and `/usr/bin/g++`?

Comment: Oh sorry about the include question!

Comment: Home g++: 5.4.0, /usr/bin's: 4.7 (older)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239193/discussion-between-madmax-and-rturrado).

Comment: 5.4: why such an old version?

Comment: @MarcGlisse I had some problems with `10.0` version installation but `5.4` is enough to build `llvm`